# How do you start a private registry with self signed certificates in Mac for Docker

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am struggling setting up a secure private registry on my local machine to use with Docker for Mac. My Mac runs Docker for Mac 18.06.1-ce-mac73 and the machine name is `DE1-AL-025`.

First I created a self signed cert in `/certs`:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 \
        -subj /CN=\*.DE1-AL-025 \
        -keyout /certs/DE1-AL-025.key -x509 -days 356 \
        -out /certs/DE1-AL-025.cert
```

Next I made the certificate available on the client (my Mac):

```
cp /certs/DE1-AL-025.cert /etc/docker/certs.d/DE1-AL-025\:5000/ca.crt
```

Finally I start the registry using the self-signed certificate:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 \
        -v /certs:/certs \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/DE1-AL-025.cert \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/DE1-AL-025.key \
        --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

When I try to push a sample image into the registry I get this error:

```
$ docker push DE1-AL-025:5000/busybox:latest
$ The push refers to repository [DE1-AL-025:5000/busybox]
$ Get https://DE1-AL-025:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is there anything I am missing? Also found a fine print under [Creating the client certificates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understanding-the-configuration):

> The version of OpenSSL in macOS is incompatible with the type of certificate Docker requires.

Answer (score 0):

1. add `DE1-AL-025` to /etc/hosts
2. open `/certs/DE1-AL-025.cert` with macOs keychain & trust it
3. reboot docker daemon & try again